# Asp.Net how to integrate Video Chat

Tags: c#, ajax, videochat

I am developing a video chat website application for a social networking website, like if i am broadcasting video, the video will be viewed by n number of users.

I have searched the web for the same but, could not find anything good.
Suggestions any one.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use silvelight for that.